# Safari element on hover with padding not filling whole area

Tags: css, safari, hover

Why in Safari (on :hover) not the whole button turns to my *hover-color* ?

(Something wrong with padding I assume)

--- Result in Safari:

[image]

--- Result in Chrome (expected):

[image]

```css
.btn,
a.btn{
    background-color: #027BFF;
    border-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 42px 20px;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out,background-color .2s ease-in-out,border-color .2s ease-in-out,box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
    transition-property: color, background-color, border-color, box-shadow;
    transition-duration: 0.2s, 0.2s, 0.2s, 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s, 0s;
}

.btn:hover, a.btn:hover {
    background-color: pink;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgb(13 110 253 / 5%);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript: something()"><span>Search</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with Safari's handling of *box-shadow* ->

```css
.btn,
a.btn{
    background-color: #027BFF;
    border-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 42px 20px;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out,background-color .2s ease-in-out,border-color .2s ease-in-out,box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
    transition-property: color, background-color, border-color, box-shadow;
    transition-duration: 0.2s, 0.2s, 0.2s, 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s, 0s;
}

.btn:hover, a.btn:hover {
    background-color: pink;
    color: #fff;
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgb(13 110 253 / 5%); */
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript: something()"><span>Search</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with `:hover` in Safari. On hover, my `a` button was not filling in completely like your example.

I narrowed the bug down to my `font-family`:

`body { font-family: Inter, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif; }`

I have Inter imported via fonts.bunny.net and if I remove Inter and use a system font the `:hover` behaves as expected. The moment I use an imported font, the issue comes back.

**I was able to fix it completely by using switching to Google Fonts instead of fonts.bunny.net**